# Set Sysdate in H2 for Testing

Tags: java, integration-testing, h2

I'm adding some integration tests to my app that will exercise sql that performs a query based on a relative date range (`current-date - 90`).

I'm using H2 in-memory, with a bunch of canned sql files (in which the date fields are hard-coded). As time progresses, the result of the query will change, and the test will be useless.

Ideally, I'd like to bootstrap H2 with a fixed timestamp that represents "now", so that the tests will always be repeatable. Is this possible?